# Combining scatter and line chart in HTML (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML, would someone please guide me in the right direction... I'm trying to combine scatter chart and line chart. The line needs to be made from a function, but that's not my main concern. I can't find out how to make the HTML file to generate one diagram that contains both scatter and line where the two are completely independent. Here are the two codes I'm trying to combine.  Could someone please tell me if this is even possible and what I need to do.  I'we tryed doing it using JSFiddle to help me, but i think I'm doing something wrong with the HTML part of the code.

***Here is the HTML part of the code:***

```
   <div id="scatter_top_x"></div>
```

```
 <button id="change-chart">Change to Classic</button>
```

***Here is the javascript part of the code:***

```
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['scatter']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line', 'corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart () {

            var materialChart;
  var classicChart;
  var button = document.getElementById('change-chart');
  var materialDiv = document.getElementById('material');
  var classicDiv = document.getElementById('classic');

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
  data.addColumn('number', "Average Temperature");
  data.addColumn('number', "Average Hours of Daylight");

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2014, 0),  -.5,  5.7],
    [new Date(2014, 1),   .4,  8.7],
    [new Date(2014, 2),   .5,   12],
    [new Date(2014, 3),  2.9, 15.3],
    [new Date(2014, 4),  6.3, 18.6],
    [new Date(2014, 5),    9, 20.9],
    [new Date(2014, 6), 10.6, 19.8],
    [new Date(2014, 7), 10.3, 16.6],
    [new Date(2014, 8),  7.4, 13.3],
    [new Date(2014, 9),  4.4,  9.9],
    [new Date(2014, 10), 1.1,  6.6],
    [new Date(2014, 11), -.2,  4.5]
  ]);

  var materialOptions = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Average Temperatures and Daylight in Iceland Throughout the Year'
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    series: {
      // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
      0: {axis: 'Temps'},
      1: {axis: 'Daylight'}
    },
    axes: {
      // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
      y: {
        Temps: {label: 'Temps (Celsius)'},
        Daylight: {label: 'Daylight'}
      }
    }
  };

  var classicOptions = {
    title: 'Average Temperatures and Daylight in Iceland Throughout the Year',
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    // Gives each series an axis that matches the vAxes number below.
    series: {
      0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
      1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
    },
    vAxes: {
      // Adds titles to each axis.
      0: {title: 'Temps (Celsius)'},
      1: {title: 'Daylight'}
    },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [new Date(2014, 0), new Date(2014, 1), new Date(2014, 2), new Date(2014, 3),
              new Date(2014, 4),  new Date(2014, 5), new Date(2014, 6), new Date(2014, 7),
              new Date(2014, 8), new Date(2014, 9), new Date(2014, 10), new Date(2014, 11)
             ]
    },
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        max: 30
      }
    }
  };

  materialChart = new google.charts.Line(materialDiv);
  classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(classicDiv);

  classicChart.draw(data, classicOptions);
  materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);

  button.onclick = function () {
    materialDiv.classList.toggle('hide');
    classicDiv.classList.toggle('hide');

    if (materialDiv.classList.contains('hide')) {
      button.innerText = 'Change to Material';
    } else {
      button.innerText = 'Change to Classic';
    }

  };

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Hours Studied');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Final');

    data.addRows([
      [0, 67],  [1, 88],  [2, 77],
      [3, 93],  [4, 85],  [5, 91],
      [6, 71],  [7, 78],  [8, 93],
      [9, 80],  [10, 82], [0, 75],
      [5, 80],  [3, 90],  [1, 72],
      [5, 75],  [6, 68],  [7, 98],
      [3, 82],  [9, 94],  [2, 79],
      [2, 95],  [2, 86],  [3, 67],
      [4, 60],  [2, 80],  [6, 92],
      [2, 81],  [8, 79],  [9, 83],
      [3, 75],  [1, 80],  [3, 71],
      [3, 89],  [4, 92],  [5, 85],
      [6, 92],  [7, 78],  [6, 95],
      [3, 81],  [0, 64],  [4, 85],
      [2, 83],  [3, 96],  [4, 77],
      [5, 89],  [4, 89],  [7, 84],
      [4, 92],  [9, 98]
    ]);

    var options = {
      width: 900,
      height: 500,
      chart: {
        title: 'Students\' Final Grades',
        subtitle: 'based on hours studied'
      },
      axes: {
        x: {
          0: {side: 'top'}
        }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Scatter(document.getElementById('scatter_top_x'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Scatter.convertOptions(options));
  }
```

Thanks!